# How to route by name net core mvc

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have one question - how to set route in view

```
<form>
<button asp-action="nextOne">Route by name</button>
</form>
```

By this name of route - nextOne (my Startup.cs)

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "nextOne",
            pattern: "home/magic",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Magic" }
                );
        });
```

I know, I can't use asp-action but I left it to show what I want to do. What instead asp-action? Once again, I want to use name "NextOne".

Please - don't give me "unlikes", but give me an answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `asp-action` to `asp-route`:

```html
<form>
    <button asp-route="nextone">Route by name</button>
</form>
```